# Python -> Copy directory while another process removes/adds files from/to it

Tags: python, concurrency, shutil

I work with Windows 10 with Python3.6.

There are two processes:

My process (COPY):
Copy a directory X (get as much as possible). (i do it via shutil.copytree)

Foreign process (CREATOR):
Deletes and Recreates files in directory X occasionally.

Problem:
One of each process 'crashes' occasionally when both processes try to operate on the directory X on the same time. I can handle exceptions in my process but do not want the foreign process to crash.

CREATOR:
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: Filepath

I can only change code for my process. Is there a way to copy files (files do not have to be complete) without disturb foreign process?

Background:
Multiple foreign processes create test reports containing many html files.
I want to copy these to one location during test execution and be able to view the current result from there.

```
import shutil, os, stat
import multiprocessing as MP
from time import sleep
import random
from traceback import format_exc

work_dir = r"C:\\tmp\\Report"
dest = r"C:\\tmp\\Report_Copy"

def CREATOR():
    while(True):
        if not(os.path.exists(work_dir)):
            os.mkdir(work_dir)
            print("CREATOR: Created %s" % work_dir)

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(work_dir, topdown=False):
            # remove current files
            for name in files:
                fullName = os.path.join(root, name)
                os.chmod(fullName, stat.S_IWRITE)
                os.remove(fullName)

        print("CREATOR: Removed %s" % work_dir)

        for i in range(1000):
            tmpPath = os.path.join(work_dir, "result%d" % i)
            with open(tmpPath, "w") as f:
                f.write("voodoo"*50000)
        print("CREATOR: Created 100 files")

        sleep(0)

def COPY():
    while(True):
        try:
            sleep(1)


            # SOLUTION FOR WINDOWS
            #######
            os.system("robocopy %s %s /E >nul 2>&1" %(work_dir, dest))
            #######


            #shutil.copytree(work_dir, dest)
            print("COPY: copied %s to %s" % (work_dir, dest))
            shutil.rmtree(dest)
            print("COPY: removed %s" % dest)
        except:
            print("COPY:\n" + format_exc())
            shutil.rmtree(dest)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.path.exists(work_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(work_dir)

    if os.path.exists(dest):
        shutil.rmtree(dest)

    P1 = MP.Process(target=CREATOR)
    P1.start()

    P2 = MP.Process(target=COPY)
    P2.start()

    P1.join()
    P2.join()
```

COPY process can fail occasionally but CREATOR process should never crash because COPY process is accessing files. The code is only an example. I can not change the code from CREATOR (foreign) process!

Comment: No. This works just fine under Linux.

Comment: Solved this by using another low lvl tool of windows -> robocopy

Comment: Write up a detailed answer then. Folks with similar problem like yours might find help in your answer!

Comment: Use in COPY Process: robocopy src dest /E see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by me by using a OS specific copy tool under Windows.

I used robocopy in COPY Process instead of `shutil.copytree` (`shutil` worked under Linux though).

```
os.system("robocopy %s %s /E >nul 2>&1" %(src, dest))
```